# printf for C %f leaving 6 0's after decimal

Tags: c, formatting, printf

```
int main ()
{
float MarysAge;

MarysAge = (int) 19.32;
printf("Mary is %f years old\n", MarysAge);

return 0;
}
```

Why does this output have the 6 0's at the end? Trying to help a friend but, I don't know C that well any help is appreciated =).

Output = Mary is 19.000000 years old

Comment: I guess it's the default. How many did you actually want?

Comment: Unsure I'll have to ask how many my friend wanted... I think they are more just looking for why there are so many 0's lol

Comment: Well, you can look at a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to understand how to change the precision.

Comment: Thanks that reference helped a lot =)

Answer (score 4):

I mis-read your question.

The number of digits can be controlled as follows...

```
printf("Mary is %.2f years old\n", MarysAge);
```

Comment: In itself, the sentence “Use %d instead of %f” might be interpreted as meaning “Use `printf("Mary is %d years old\n", MarysAge);` where `MarysAge` is of type `float`. This would not be very good advice.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Agreed. I redid my answer once I had re-read the question :)

Answer (score 2):

The default precision of %f is 6,output 6 numbers after point.
And (int)  Rounded down.
First  19.32 became 19 on (int),
then became 19.000000 on %f.